# pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file while reading csv files

Tags: python

I am running a program to read csv files and save data in lists to later be re-written in a csv file with a different layout. Here is the code:

```
def read_csv(filename):
    date = ["Date"]
    high = ["High"]
    low = ["Low"]
    close = ["Close"]
    volume = ["Volume"]
    adj_close = ["Adj Close"]

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=date)
    print(df)
    Date.append(df)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=high)
    print(df)
    High.append(df)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=low)
    print(df)
    Low.append(df)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=close)
    print(df)
    Close.append(df)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=volume)
    print(df)
    Volume.append(df)

    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=adj_close)
    print(df)
    Adj_Close.append(df)
```

But, everytime I run it, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1883, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "c:/Users/sande/Desktop/Vihaan/ThirdPartySoftware/Python/VisualStudiosCode/DadWork/Converter.py", line 116, in to_av
    createData(filename)
  File "c:/Users/sande/Desktop/Vihaan/ThirdPartySoftware/Python/VisualStudiosCode/DadWork/Converter.py", line 93, in createData
    copyCol(i, 1, len(Date), filename)
  File "c:/Users/sande/Desktop/Vihaan/ThirdPartySoftware/Python/VisualStudiosCode/DadWork/Converter.py", line 72, in copyCol
    read_csv(filename)
  File "c:/Users/sande/Desktop/Vihaan/ThirdPartySoftware/Python/VisualStudiosCode/DadWork/Converter.py", line 31, in read_csv
    df = pd.read_csv(filename, usecols=date)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 686, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 452, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 946, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1178, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\sande\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2008, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 540, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file
```

My running code is here:

```
def copyCol(filename):
    read_csv(filename)
```

Can anyone tell me why this is happening ?

Comment: check if you file doesn't have header or is empty

Comment: It has both... So

Comment: can you share the header in the csv file?